# Sum Values based on unique ID

Tags: vba, excel

Just started a new job. I'm automating a month-end report and I'm new at VBA. Been googling most of my issues with success, but I've finally run into a wall. In essence I'm downloading some data from SAP and from there I need to build a report.

My question is: How to do a sumif function using loops in VBA?

Data pull:
Sheet1 contains a product code and purchase amounts (columns A & B) respectively. One product code can have several purchases (several rows with the same product code).

Steps so far:

1. I arranged the data sheet1 to be in ascending order.
2. Copied unique values for the product codes onto another sheet (sheet2). So Sheet2 has a list of all the products (in ascending order).
3. I want to get the sum of all purchases in sheet2 column B (per product code). I know how to do this using formulas, but I need to automate this as much as possible. (+ I'm genuinely interested in figuring this out)

This is what I did in VBA so far: 
Sub Macro_test()

```
Dim tb As Worksheet
Dim tb2 As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim lrow As Long

Set tb = Sheets("sheet1")
Set tb2 = Sheets("sheet2")
lrow = tb.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lrow
For y = 2 To lrow
    If tb2.Cells(x, 1).Value = tb.Cells(y, 1).Value Then
        tb2.Cells(x, 2).Value = tb.Cells(y, 2).Value
    End If
Next y
Next x
```

End Sub

If i'm not mistaken, for each product_code in sheet2 col A, I'm looping through all the product codes in sheet1 and getting back the LAST value it finds, instead of the sum of all values... I understand why it doesn't work, I just don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using a `SumIf` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement overwrites the value of `tb2.Cells(x, 2).Value` at each iteration:

```
tb2.Cells(x, 2).Value = tb.Cells(y, 2).Value
```

Instead, I think you need to keep *adding to it*:

```
tb2.Cells(x, 2).Value = tb2.Cells(x, 2).Value + tb.Cells(y, 2).Value
```

But I don't like the looks of your double-loop which uses only one `lrow` variable to represent the "last row" on the two different worksheets, that could be causing some issues.

Or, in your loop do something like this which I think will avoid the duplicate sum. Still, assumes the second worksheet doesn't initially have any value in

```
' Base our lRow on Sheet2, we don't care how many rows in Sheet1.
lrow = tb2.Cells(tb2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cl as Range
Set cl = tb.Cells(2,1)  'Our initial cell value / ID

For x = 2 to lRow   '## Look the rows on Sheet 2
    '## Check if the cell on Sheet1 == cell on Sheet2
    While cl.Value = tb2.Cells(x,1).Value  
       '## Add cl.Value t- the tb2 cell:
       tb2.Cells(x, 2).Value = tb2.Cells(x, 2).Value + cl.Offset(0,1).Value
       Set cl = cl.Offset(1)  '## Reassign to the next Row
    Wend
Next
```

But it would be better to omit the double-loop and simply use VBA to do 1 of the following:

## 1. Insert The Formula:

(See [Scott Holtzman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43854551/1467082)).

This approach is better for lots of reasons, not the least of which is that the WorksheetFunction is optimized already, so it should arguably perform better though on a small dataset the difference in runtime will be negligible. The other reason is that it's stupid to reinvent the wheel unless you have a very good justification for doing so, so in this case, why write your own version of code that accomplishes what the built-in `SumIf` already does and is specifically designed to do?

This approach is also ideal if the reference data may change, as the cell formulas will automatically recalculate based on the data in Sheet1.

## 2. Evaluate the formula & replace with values only:

If you prefer not to retain the formula, then a simple `Value` assignment can remove the formula but retain the results:

```
With .Range(.Range("B2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(, 1))
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Sheet1!C[-1]:C[-1],RC[-1],Sheet1!C:C)"
    .Value = .Value  'This line gets rid of the formula but retains the values
End With
```

Use this approach if you will be removing Sheet1, as removing the referents will break the formula on Sheet2, or if you otherwise want the Sheet2 to be a "snapshot" instead of a dynamic summation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! 

The code works except for products which only have one line of data. In that case it, doubles the actual value. Can you help? 

wrt to your comment about using VBA to insert the formula. Do you say that because it reduces the runtime? More simple? Or some other reason?

Comment: I answered the second question in revised answer. Not sure about the "doubles the actual value" problem. From your description of the worksheets and what's on them, this should not happen. The code above assumes the value in `tb2.Cells(x,2)` is initially empty. If that's not the case, then it is not as you described (*Copied unique values for the product codes onto another sheet (sheet2). So Sheet2 has a list of all the products )* or there is more data on sheet2 that you didn't describe :)

Comment: After playing around with both codes I ended up taking your recommendation and using the the r1c1 code. Works great for what I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this automated, take advantage of VBA to place the formula for you. It's very quick and easy using `R1C1` notation.

Complete code (tested):

```
Dim tb As Worksheet
Dim tb2 As Worksheet

Set tb = Sheets("sheet1")
Set tb2 = Sheets("sheet2")

Dim lrow As Long

lrow = tb.Cells(tb.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

tb.Range("A2:A" & lrow).Copy tb2.Range("A2")

With tb2

    .Range("A2").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates 1

    With .Range(.Range("B2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(, 1))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Sheet1!C[-1]:C[-1],RC[-1],Sheet1!C:C)"
    End With

End With
```

*Note that with `R1C1` notation the C and R are not referring to column or row*  **letters** *. Rather they are the column and row offsets from the place where the formula is stored on the specific worksheet. In this case `Sheet!C[-1]` refers to the entire A column of sheet one, since the formula is entered into column B of sheet 2.*

Comment: Hey, I ended up using this code instead of trying to do loops. Works much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a neat little algorithm (if you can call it that) that does what you want them spits out grouped by totals into another sheet. Basically it loops through the first section to get unique names/labels and stores them into an array. Then it iterates through that array and adds up values if the current iteration matches what the current iteration of the nested loop position.

```
Private Sub that()
    Dim this As Variant
    Dim that(9, 1) As String
    Dim rowC As Long
    Dim colC As Long

    this = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").UsedRange
    rowC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    colC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").UsedRange.Columns.Count

    Dim thisname As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim x As Long

    For i = LBound(this, 1) To UBound(this, 1)
        thisname = this(i, 1)
        For x = LBound(that, 1) To UBound(that, 1)
            If thisname = that(x, 0) Then
                Exit For
            ElseIf thisname <> that(x, 0) And that(x, 0) = vbNullString Then
                that(x, 0) = thisname
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
    Next i

    For i = LBound(that, 1) To UBound(that, 1)
        thisname = that(i, 0)
        For j = LBound(this, 1) To UBound(this, 1)
            If this(j, 1) = thisname Then
                thisvalue = thisvalue + this(j, 2)
            End If
        Next j
        that(i, 1) = thisvalue
        thisvalue = 0
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet5").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(1, 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(rowC, colC)).Value2 = that

End Sub
```

Yay arrays

Comment: Hey I didn't have the time today to check this out but it looks neat. I'll have to try it with my data when I have the time. Thanks for the post.

Comment: @nafall keep in mind that your array might need to be adjusted for size. Or you could learn hwo to redim preserve your array within the code